# .format return wrong hour

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to parse this date:

```
Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT
```

into this:

```
Tue, 27 Oct 2015 18:00:00 GMT
```

for do this I've this code:

```
start = moment(moment("Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + "18:00").format("ddd, D MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss") + " GMT";
```

but the problem's that this code return this:

> Tue, 27 Oct 2015 06:00:00 GMT

instead of `18:00:00` Why happean this? Check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/2221/)

Answer (score 0):

When you format de date, you need to pass the `HH:mm:ss` time format to tell momentjs it's 24h format. Notice the capital H:

`start = moment(moment("Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + "18:00").format("ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + " GMT";`

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a83ob6dy/